# Getting invalid token from Auth0 in my new Expo app

Tags: react-native, jwt, expo, auth0

I’m implementing Auth0 authentication on a new Expo app following this example:
https://github.com/expo/auth0-example

It seems to make a call to Auth0 and successfully obtain a token but immediately after logging the response in the console, it also gives me the following error:

> Possible Unhandled Promise Rejection (id: 0) [InvalidTokenError:
>   Invalid token specified: Unexpected token V in JSON at position 0]

The response I get is this:

```
params:
access_token: “Vku7HOclH7pVi52bmzGHga89VwpfK_Y4”
exp://10.0.0.215:19000/–/expo-auth-session: “”
expires_in: “7200”
scope: “openid profile”
token_type: “Bearer”
proto: Object
type: “success”
url: “exp://10.0.0.215:19000/–/expo-auth-session#access_token=Vku7HOclH7pVi52bmzGHga89VwpfK_Y4&scope=openid%20profile&expires_in=7200&token_type=Bearer”
```

When I check the `access_token` on [jwt.io](https://jwt.io), it indicates an invalid signature. Any idea what may be the issue here?

Here’s my full code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { AuthSession } from 'expo';
import { Alert, Button, View, Text } from 'react-native';
import jwtDecoder from 'jwt-decode';

import styles from '../constants/styles';

const auth0ClientId = 'my_client_id_for_my_mobile_app_from_Auth0_dashboard';
const auth0Domain = 'https://mydomain.auth0.com';

  /**
   * Converts an object to a query string.
   */
function toQueryString(params) {
  return '?' + Object.entries(params)
    .map(([key, value]) => `${encodeURIComponent(key)}=${encodeURIComponent(value)}`)
    .join('&');
}

export default class Login extends Component {

  constructor(props) {

    super(props);
    this.state = {
      username: null
    };
  }

  _loginWithAuth0 = async () => {

    const redirectUrl = AuthSession.getRedirectUrl();
    console.log(`Redirect URL (add this to Auth0): ${redirectUrl}`);
    const result = await AuthSession.startAsync({
      authUrl: `${auth0Domain}/authorize` + toQueryString({
        client_id: auth0ClientId,
        response_type: 'token',
        scope: 'openid profile',
        redirect_uri: redirectUrl,
      }),
    });

    console.log(result);
    if (result.type === 'success') {
      this.handleParams(result.params);
    }
  }

  handleParams = (responseObj) => {

    if (responseObj.error) {
      Alert.alert('Error', responseObj.error_description
        || 'something went wrong while logging in');
      return;
    }
    const encodedToken = responseObj.access_token;
    const decodedToken = jwtDecoder(encodedToken, { header: true });
    const username = decodedToken.name;
    debugger;
    this.setState({ username });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.welcomeScreen}>
        <Text>Welcome to My Expo App!</Text>
        <Button title="Login with Auth0" onPress={this._loginWithAuth0} />
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

P.S. My Expo app is using SDK version 31.0.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Access Token for non-Custom APIs are in opaque (Similar to the token you have received) and not a JWT. This is because you have not set an `audience` in the Authorization URL. Auth0 will only give [JWT Access Tokens](https://auth0.com/docs/tokens/set-access-token-format) for Custom APIs.

The ID Token you received will be in JWT format, since you requested for `openid` scope.